# PlotPoints does not work properly in ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I want to get surface with "bad" quality, so I decrease number of sample points in both parameters:

```
g = ParametricPlot3D[
   {R Cos[ϕ], R Sin[ϕ], z}
   , {ϕ, 0, 2 π}
   , {z, 0, 1}
   , PlotPoints -> {3, 2}
   , MaxRecursion -> 0
   , PlotRange -> All
]
```

but `g` is build of much more points than I expected:

`Length@g[[1, 1]]`

gives

`321`

In 2-dim case, it works as I expect:

```
g = ParametricPlot3D[
{R Cos[ϕ], R Sin[ϕ], 1}
  , {ϕ, 0, 2 π}
  , PlotPoints -> 5
  , MaxRecursion -> 0
]
```

and

`g[[1, 1, 3, 3]]`

is a line made of 5 points:

```
Line[
  {
    {0.4, 6.28319*10^-7, 1.}, 
    {0.0239846, 0.39928, 1.}, 
    {-0.39999, -0.00283338, 1.}, 
    {-0.0137472, -0.399764, 1.}, 
    {0.4, -6.28319*10^-7, 1.}
  }
]
```

*Mathematica v.10.2*

Comment: What is the value of `R`? I can't reproduce you problem , I get `Length@g[[1,1]] -> 3`.

Comment: @rhermans The code in the question should be `Length@g[[1, 1, 1]]`, which yields `321`.  There is something strange here.

Comment: Use `Mesh -> All` or `Mesh -> None`.

Comment: @rhermans R=0.4

Answer (score 1):

The plot corresponding to the first block of code in the question is, with R = 1 for specificity,

```
g = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[ϕ], Sin[ϕ], z}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {z, 0, 1}, 
    PlotPoints -> {3, 2}, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Either by examining

```
g // Normal // InputForm
```

or simply by counting mesh lines, we see that the default mesh is given for this plot by `Mesh -> 15`.  Such a detailed mesh cannot be determined accurately by `PlotPoints -> {3, 2}`, so Mathematica computes more points.  To illustrate this behavior, generate plots for various numbers of mesh lines:

```
GraphicsGrid[Partition[Table[
    ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[ϕ], Sin[ϕ], z}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {z, 0, 1}, 
        PlotPoints -> {3, 2}, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotRange -> All, 
        Mesh -> n, PlotLabel -> n],
{n, 0, 8}], 3], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

The question requests a surface with "bad" quality.  Plots in the first row of the grid above probably qualify.  (By the way, the shading of the `n = 0` plot above does not match what Mathematica actually produced, which is shading with a uniform gradient.)

Comment: For the OP's example, if `PlotPoints -> pp`, then `Mesh -> pp - 2` gives mesh lines corresponding to the desired plot points (whether `pp = {n1, n2}` or `pp = n`).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good to know.  Thanks.

Comment: so, it means these two options are correlated! I l always treated Meshas an option used only for putting grid lines on a surface,

Comment: @sebqas Your supposition usually is correct, but `Mesh` sometimes is used for other purposes.  In this case, I would prefer that Mathematica either return a warning message that `Mesh` is too large for the choice of `PlotPoints` or that its default value change with the value of `PlotPoints`.